# Proper way to render list of objects

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to render a list of objects first. Then when a user scroll up, I make an HTTP request to load more data.

Pseudocode:

```
// Main.vue

const {elements,showNext} = useElements()

 const loadMore=()=>{
      showNext()
 }

    <div onScrollUp="loadMore">
        <div v-for"element in elements" :key:"element.key">
         {{element.name}}
       </div>
    </div>
```

```
// useElements.vue


        const list = ref(1)
        const {data,isLoading,error} = useFetch(list)
        const elements =ref([{}...{}]) 

        const showNext =()=>{ 
             list.value+=1
            }

          watch((data)=>{
          elements.value.push(...data.value)
            })

            return {
              elements,
              showNext
            }
```

The problem is when I fetch new elements all the list re-render in addition to previous rendered ones.

I expect to render only new elements and keep old elements in place.
Am I doing someting wrong?

Comment: Just a question, what is this `[{}...{}]` robot face supposed to do? Isn't that just a complicated way to have an empty array or array with empty object? I get a syntax error in the browser console when I type that in.

Comment: @PeterPointer ah no just to tell it is an array of objects, of course it contains data.

Comment: @PeterPointer I forgot to mention also that I'm using some watcher in userElements composables (I edited the question now). After debugging, I think the issue is coming from there.

Comment: My guess is that if you have new elements at the top after scrolling up, the list must also have new elements at the top. So naturally the list visually re-renders the entries. If you provide example objects instead and a way to fake the loading of elements, you could make your code a runnable snippet with the `<>` icon in the question editor - select Vuejs on the left. Makes it easier to experiment with it and people can just copy the snippet to the answer and show a possible fix.

Comment: With my current implementation it re-renders the hole list. I tried to simulate the same behavior without watch (with setInterval every second I fetch new data and push it in elements) and It worked as expected(it renders only new elements). I do not know what is the issue in watching new data then push it in the array. How Can I add new coming data without using watch ?

Comment: IIRC the re-rendering is triggered by the key, as in `:key:"element.key"`. If fetching new results changes their key then they'll re-render even though their content is the same. This can happen if the key represents the position in the query result, rather than a unique id.

Comment: Yes , I'm using a unique key.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the issue is not related to how I save and fetch data. It is related to fetching state (Loading, error) every time I request new data, loading state is triggered so the list of elements dissapear (code below). Therefore the whole list re-render since it was not there when loading state triggered.

```
     <div v-if="isLoading">   //when data is fetching isLoading = true
          <p> loading </p>
     </div>
     <div v-if="error">
          <p> error</p>
     </div>


     <div v-else>  //therefore this block will disappear and next 
time (isLoading=false,error=false), elements will render the whole list
             <div onScrollUp="loadMore">
                <div v-for"element in elements" :key:"element.key"> 
                 {{element.name}}
                </div>
             </div>
         <div/>
```